# ITerm 2 Terminal not working with ZSH and agnoster - specifically my prompt

Tags: terminal, zsh, oh-my-zsh

I've installed as the various tutorials say - such as https://ruigomes.me/blog/perfect-iterm-osx-terminal-installation/

However my prompt isn't changing. Can anyone see anything wrong with my Zsh file?

I've run `source ~/.zshrc`

````
```bash

alias gb='git branch'


# Path to your oh-my-zsh installation.
export ZSH=$HOME/.oh-my-zsh

 #Set name of the theme to load.
export PATH="/usr/local/bin:$PATH"
# Look in ~/.oh-my-zsh/themes/
# Optionally, if you set this to "random", it'll load a random theme each
# time that oh-my-zsh is loaded.
ZSH_THEME="agnoster"

# Example aliases
# alias zshconfig="mate ~/.zshrc"
# alias ohmyzsh="mate ~/.oh-my-zsh"

 #Uncomment the following line to use case-sensitive completion.
export CLICOLOR=1
# CASE_SENSITIVE="true"

# Uncomment the following line to disable bi-weekly auto-update checks.
# DISABLE_AUTO_UPDATE="true"

# Uncomment the following line to change how often to auto-update (in days).
# export UPDATE_ZSH_DAYS=13

# Uncomment the following line to disable colors in ls.
# DISABLE_LS_COLORS="true"

# Uncomment the following line to disable auto-setting terminal title.
# DISABLE_AUTO_TITLE="true"

# Uncomment the following line to disable command auto-correction.
# DISABLE_CORRECTION="true"

# Uncomment the following line to display red dots whilst waiting for completion.
# COMPLETION_WAITING_DOTS="true"

# Uncomment the following line if you want to disable marking untracked files
# under VCS as dirty. This makes repository status check for large repositories
# much, much faster.
# DISABLE_UNTRACKED_FILES_DIRTY="true"

# Uncomment the following line if you want to change the command execution time
# stamp shown in the history command output.
# The optional three formats: "mm/dd/yyyy"|"dd.mm.yyyy"|"yyyy-mm-dd"
# HIST_STAMPS="mm/dd/yyyy"

# Would you like to use another custom folder than $ZSH/custom?
# ZSH_CUSTOM=/path/to/new-custom-folder

# Which plugins would you like to load? (plugins can be found in ~/.oh-my-zsh/plugins/*)
# Custom plugins may be added to ~/.oh-my-zsh/custom/plugins/
 NORMAL  ./.zshrc                                                  unix  utf-8  zsh   12%    18:1
"~/.zshrc" 147L, 5834C
alias gb='git branch'
alias grh="git reset --hard upstream/master"
alias gs='git status -sb' # upgrade your git if -sb breaks for you. it's fun.
alias ipn='jupyter notebook'
alias grep='grep --color=auto' # Always highlight grep search term
alias ping='ping -c 5'      # Pings with 5 packets, not unlimited
alias df='df -h'            # Disk free, in gigabytes, not bytes
alias du='du -h -c'         # Calculate total disk usage for a folder
alias sgi='sudo gem install' # Install ruby stuff
alias clj='clj-env-dir'        # Clojure helper
alias clr='clear;echo "Currently logged in on $(tty), as $(whoami) in directory $(pwd)."'
alias tt='tt++ $HOME/.ttconf'
alias svim="sudo vim" # Run vim as super user
alias subl="sublime" # Run sublime with the correct locale
alias emc="emacsclient -n" # no blocking terminal waiting for edit
export PATH="/Applications/domino:$PATH"
export PATH=$PATH:/home/peadar/domino #added by domino
export LANG="en_GB.UTF-8"
export LANGUAGE="en_GB.UTF-8"
export LC_ALL="en_GB.UTF-8"
alias sublf="subl . &"

export PATH="/Users/peadarcoyle/anaconda/bin:$PATH"
export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH
export PATH="$HOME/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/bin:$PATH"
export EDITOR='vim'
#export DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH=$HOME/anaconda/lib:$DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH
export AWS_KEYPAIR_NAME="analysis"
export AWS_SSH_KEY_FILENAME="~/.ssh/analysis.pem"
#export AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID="AKIAINBSZAFULNRYH5BA"
#export VPC="vpc-67697705"
export PATH=/Users/peadarcoyle/.local/bin:$PATH
export AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY="CeHGManx2Xwv22CUOh5YVOPPPbs8fu3hPxitAlOt"
. /Users/peadarcoyle/torch/install/bin/torch-activate
PATH="/usr/local/opt/coreutils/libexec/gnubin:$PATH"
MANPATH="/usr/local/opt/coreutils/libexec/gnuman:$MANPATH"
export PATH=/Users/peadarcoyle/lein:$PATH
#export SPARK_HOME = ~/srv/spark
export PATH = $SPARK_HOME/bin:$PATH
export PATH="$PATH:/path/to/elixir/bin"
export ARCHFLAGS=-Wno-error=unused-command-line-argument-hard-error-in-future
export DOCKER_HOST=tcp://192.168.59.103:2376
export DOCKER_CERT_PATH=/Users/peadarcoyle/.boot2docker/certs/boot2docker-vm
export DOCKER_TLS_VERIFY=1
export PATH=/Users/peadarcoyle/anaconda/bin/psql:$PATH

export GOROOT=/usr/local/opt/go/libexec
export GOPATH=$HOME/.go
export PATH=$PATH:$GOROOT/bin:$GOPATH/bin
alias curl="noglob curl"
export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home/
```
````

Comment: After you made the changes to `~/.zshrc`, did you run `source ~/.zshrc`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this by starting with a clean Zsh file and slowly adding attributes. I imagine I was overwriting one of the environment variables.